# Is there a better way to architect Application Options?

Tags: c#

I have an Class `Translator` which has two instances of `Parser(Options options)` - an input parser, and output parser.  They each get their own options.

Each parser has a list of `ElementParser(Options option)` which passes the options down.

If the each parser has a hundred elements, these means there are over a hundred refs to each option instance.

This seems excessive.

The obvious answer is to create a static `Parser.Options` property, but traditional wisdom says to stay away from them.

So is there a better way to architect this?

Here is a working sample:

```
public class Options {
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

public class ElementParser {
    public object ElementData { get; set; }
    public ElementParser(Options options) {
        this.Options = options;
    }
    public Options Options { get; set; }
    public void DoesSomethingWithOptions() {
        if (Options.Value == 1)
        {
            //Do something();
        }
        else
        {
            //Do something else();
        }
    }
}

public class SegmentParser{

    public object SegmentData { get; set; }
    public Options Options { get; set; }
    public List<ElementParser> ElementParsers { get; set; } 

    public SegmentParser(Options options) {
        this.Options = options;

    }

    public void AddABunchOfElements() {
        this.ElementParsers = new List<ElementParser>() {new ElementParser(this.Options), new ElementParser(this.Options)};
    }

}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args) {

        var options1 = new Options() {Value = 1};
        var options2 = new Options() {Value = 2};

        var segment1 = new SegmentParser(options1);
        segment1.AddABunchOfElements();

        var segment2 = new SegmentParser(options2);
        segment2.AddABunchOfElements();
        //There are now 3 references of each options.  If there were 100 elements, there would be over 200 references.
    }
}
```

Here is a second attempt using a static property.  Notice that the Parser class is subclassed, so there is really only one instance of the static property.  This sample does work correctly.

```
public class Options
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

public class Parser{
}

public class Parser1  : Parser
{
    public Parser1(Options options) {
        Options = options;
    }
    public static Options Options { get; set; }
}

public class Parser2  : Parser {
    public Parser2(Options options) {
        Options = options;
    }
    public static Options Options { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args) {

        var options1 = new Options();
        options1.Value = 1;

        var options2 = new Options();
        options2.Value = 2;

        var test1 = new Parser1(options1);

        var test2 = new Parser2(options2);

        Console.WriteLine(Parser1.Options.Value); //Should be 1
        Console.WriteLine(Parser2.Options.Value); //Should be 2;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with what you've posted.  A few hundred references to an object is not that big in the grand scheme of things.

I'd only make `Options` static if there is only one `Options`(which there isn't)

---

If `Options` is more associated with `Segment` than it is with `Element` than your `Element` might not even need to have the `Options` property, it can simply use `Segment`'s or it can take an `Options` parameter in it's method.

Right now your program is abstracted enough that it's impossible to tell whether or not that would be appropriate, but it's something to keep in mind.

Comment: Yes, it is most closely associated to the Segment.  It will never change at the element level.  I could actual make it static at the Segment Level, but again, I have fear of Static properties.

Comment: "making it static at the segment level" doesn't make very much sense to me.  There is only 1 of a particular static object, not one per instance.

Comment: Sam, I did a sample and added it to the above question sample.  Each parser is actually a subclass, and each subclass has it's own static property, so there is only one of a particular static object.  I am not saying this is a good idea, just a possible one.

Comment: @GregHollywood Your second example doesn't have the collections of `Elements`, but if it did, how do your `Elements` know which `Parser`'s `Options` to use?

Comment: Good point.  I think your correct in your original comment that there is nothing wrong with the references.  There is finite number of element parsers, so it's really not an issue.

Answer (score 1):

`Segment` and `Element` seem to be just plain DTO's, which should thus not be able with their own construction.

`AddABunchOfElements()` belongs in a `SegmentWriter` instance, containing one or more `Options`.

Comment: You are correct. I updated the sample to show that they are not DTO.

Comment: @Greg your edit shows that your parser does not only parse, but also hold the data. Refactor that, make an `ElementParser` spit out a list of `Element`s. Then you only need one `ElementParser` instance that can contain all the options.